# Is auto increment guaranteed to keep incrementing?

Tags: sql, database, h2, auto-increment

If I have a integer column in h2 and use auto increment for it, is it guaranteed to always increment the last inserted value?

-- If some intermediate row is deleted.

-- If last inserted row is deleted.

-- If all rows are deleted using `delete from myTable`

EDIT: The reason I need the numbering continued (and I would expect this to be the normal behavior) is I am looking to archive older data to keep current tables short.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The auto-incremented value is guaranteed to always be larger than the previous value.  It is not guaranteed to always be exactly one more than the last successfully inserted value.

The latter requires much more overhead and is not (generally) worth the additional effort.

Comment: as a side note, if we truncate the table, the numbering resets

Comment: I am looking for particular case of h2. Could not find much documentation on this. Can you provide some reference. Also, when you say `larger than the previous value` does that mean `larger than the highest value currently in db` or `larger than that of the bottom row`, (which could change if we delete that row)?